# set an alarm using time.sleep() function

Tags: python, time, sleep

I wrote a code that symbolizes sleep until 7 am.
basically system will keep printing "sleeping" a few times
then the clock starts ringing (system will print "Hey wake up! It's 7!" **once**)
and then continues to print "sleeping" again.
but I do not know how to set an alarm.
here's what I've tried:

```
from time import sleep
def Type(dialog):
    '''
This function will be used to add a nice typing effect
and that's all
'''
    counter=0 #This value helps to find out if the sentence is finished
    speed=0.04 #This value changes typing speed
    for char in dialog:
        sleep(speed)
        print(char,end='',flush=True)
        counter+=1 
        if counter==len(dialog):
            print('') #This helps to seprate two sentences in two seprate lines

def alarm():
    '''
This function have to work in backgroung
without interrupting sleeping finction
'''
    sleep(5)
    Type("Hey wake up! It's 7!")
    sleeping()
    
    
def sleeping():
    for num in range(1,61):
        Type(f'Sleeping {num} . . .')
        alarm()

sleeping()
```

This doesn't do what I want.

I want the alarm() function to countdown 5 seconds while system is printing "sleeping",
after the countdown is finished I want system to print "Hey wake up! It's 7!" **once**
and then continue to print "sleeping"

I've tried using *Timer* method from *threading* framework like such:

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Timer

def Type(dialog):
    
    '''
This function will be used to add a nice typing effect
and that's all
'''
    counter=0 #This value helps to find out if the sentence is finished
    speed=0.04 #This value changes typing speed
    for char in dialog:
        sleep(speed)
        print(char,end='',flush=True)
        counter+=1 
        if counter==len(dialog):
            print('') #This helps to seprate two sentences in two seprate lines

def alarm():
    '''
This function have to work in backgroung
without interrupting sleeping finction
'''

    Type("Hey wake up! It's 7!")
    sleeping()
    
    
def sleeping():
    for num in range(1,61):
        Type(f'Sleeping {num} . . .')

t=Timer(5.0,alarm())
t.start()
sleeping()
```

It didn't work how I wanted it to.

Comment: `sleep` is not really an appropriate tool here, better use a scheduler (e.g. [schedule](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
t=Timer(5.0,alarm())
```

You called function `alarm` and then rammed output value of that function, instead of function itself, you should use function itself as 2nd argument, consider following simple example

```
from threading import Timer
def alarm():
    print("WAKEUP")
t = Timer(5.0, alarm)
t.start()
```

will after 5 second print

```
WAKEUP
```

Observe that you are exploiting fact that functions are 1st class citizens in `python`, so they could be passed as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with asyncio. It's a library that allows for concurrent code using async/await syntax.

```
import asyncio

async def alarm():
    print(f"Wake up it's 7am!")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def sleeping(loop):
    for number in range(1, 61):
        if(number == 5):
            asyncio.ensure_future(alarm())
        print(f"Sleeping... {number}")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(sleeping(loop))
```

If you don't want to use threading or any concurrency you could also change what is returned from `Sleeping...` to `Wale`  when `num == 5`